# upgrade from ubuntu server 1804 to 2004 on Proliant ml150g6 loses ethernet

Tags: ethernet, adapter

I had the 1804 server running for a number of years. I upgraded to 20:04 without problems, but on rebooting find no connection to network. A Kubuntu 23:04 usb driver boots and has a ethernet connection, so I think the ethernet driver is problematic. How can I get the adapter working?

Walter

Comment: Which kernel stack are you using?  The default for Ubuntu Server is GA or the older kernel, meaning 4.15 (GA) for 18.04, and 5.4 (GA) for 20.04, where 23.04 (EOL) used 6.2.  You could switch to the HWE kernel stack of 20.04 which is 5.15 (*newer and closer to 23.04*) but if you were using HWE on 18.04 (ie. 5.15) switching to GA will return you to using 5.15.  What was your 18.04 using?  (GA being 4.15 or HWE or 5.4).  Did you explore your system for issues (eg. `sudo lshw -C network` etc & your hardware is recognized) or are your issues traffic/IP related?

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl NetworkManager service`. Also do: `service NetworkManager status` and `service --status-all`.

Comment: network:DISABLED

Comment: failed to start raise network interfaces